# What equivalent in MIDP programing to the JButton of swing-application?

Tags: java, user-interface, applet, midp

In swing(GUI) application I used JButtons.
Now I need the same application in MIDP and I'm conuse...
I need Idea for what to use with and an example of how to use it and what kind of listener might possible fits.(Because I need to refresh the shown screen after every click on a button)

And one more question: I use Netbins with the simulator of cell-phone.The screen is very tiny,
so is there any way to make this screen larger,In case I need to show something too width?
Lets say,something like 11-15 buttons...

Comment: Even partial answer would be good,I really need direction,and this is really important to me....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything that's exactly equivalent to a JButton, but I think you could solve your problem by implementing a Command though.  I found a lot of examples:

- [MIDP Programming with J2ME](http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/10934_1561591_1/MIDP-Programming-with-J2ME.htm) (This one is a bit long.  It's actually an entire chapter from a book and the Command example starts on [page 4](http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/10934_1561591_4/MIDP-Programming-with-J2ME.htm).)
- [Enterprise J2ME: developing mobile Java applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=vpMJoAoJIuAC&pg=PA421&lpg=PA421&dq=ava+midp+button&source=bl&ots=l4me8Rdlb1&sig=EBpFIOBvZBCaU5ZMN5ttlUPYHlU&hl=en&ei=cdV-TPHdKcGqlAeO85jvAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBYQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=ava%20midp%20button&f=false) (Also a book, but I linked to the relevant section.)
- [J2ME Programming (Part I)](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/pearce/j2me/J2ME%20Programming.htm) (I like the CommandProcessor.java code example in this one.)
- [Visual Mobile Designer Custom Components: Creating Login Screens](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/loginscreen.html)
- [Add Command to MIDlet](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0430__J2ME/AddCommandtoMIDlet.htm) (This one has the shortest and clearest example code, but it unfortunately doesn't have a screen shot of the final result.)

Answer (score 0):

> And one more question: I use Netbins with the simulator of cell-phone.The screen is very tiny, so is there any way to make this screen larger,In case I need to show something too width? Lets say,something like 11-15 buttons...

There is a way to choose an emulator with larger size screen. Last time I checked, [Netbeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) documentation had instructions on how to do that.

- Though, before doing so, I would recommend you to find out whether the *real device* you're targeting will have such a screen. Because if its screen will be as *tiny* as the default emulator then your UI might look totally different from what you designed with large size emulator.

Take for example *11-15 buttons* you mention - do you expect real device to have screen large enough to display these conveniently for user?